# NEXTJS 14: sever error with alchemy API missing response (requestBody="{\"method\":\"alchemy_getTokenBalances\"

Tags: reactjs, next.js

> serverError: TypeError: Referrer "client" is not a valid URL.
> at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:5361:21)
> at R (D:\BIT\tesst\tesst\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\next-server\app-page.runtime.dev.js:35:342709)
> ... 30 lines matching cause stack trace ...
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {

can you help me fix this problem, i try to call API Alchemy from component like this

```js
    import { Alchemy, Network } from "alchemy-sdk";
    const settings = {
      apiKey: "key key", // i hide my key
      network: Network.ETH_MAINNET, 
    };
    function App() {
      const alchemy = new Alchemy(settings);

      useEffect(() => {
        const func = async () => {
          return await alchemy.core.getTokenBalances('0x2EeEa57cD51DF77163Fae7A056053f402d8E17CB');
        };

        func().then((r) => console.log("", r));
      }, []);
      return (
        <>
          <div></div>
        </>
      );
    }
```

and it works

but i call it by server nextjs 14, it has problem like title